# impossible to set background-image of a div for SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I have created a Sandbox solution which contains two modules: one for Master page and other for Site Assets (js, css and images).

I have used `background-image: url("")` in my style sheet file to add image to my dives. When I deploy the sandbox solution my dev environment it works great but on SharePoint Online none of the `background-image:url("")` works at all.
Here is one of elements in my css file:

```
#page-wrapper {
      background: url("/_catalogs/masterpage/munters/assets/UI/Images/backgrounds/site-bg.gif") repeat-x left top rgb(255, 255, 255); padding-top: 22px; padding-bottom: 50px; border-bottom-color: rgb(222, 222, 222); border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; min-width: 985px;
}
```

Comment: How is URL structure, eg: http://xxx.zzz.com/sites/ or something similar?

Comment: yes, it is developer site on office 365 for developers, and the url is domain.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite.

Comment: My experience is that, simply put, SharePoint is not a big fan of recognizing style information in div tags. Have you tried wrapping the section in a <span> tag instead and adding the class?

Comment: I usually put the URL into the url() without quotes, so url(/path/to/css).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the URL path of your img.

`/_catalogs/etc/` will link to `domain.sharepoint.com/_catalogs` , and if the image only exists under your `/sites/mysite` it will be blank.

Try changing to either:

`/sites/mysite/_catalogs/etc` or

`../_catalogs/masterpage` if the css file is in the site assests.

I don't do branding, I guess there is a better way to add the URL paths.

Comment: no it was not the case, I tested both on my dev environment and online. it stopped working on both. (before it worked on my dev). it most have something with sharepoint 2013. I had created a free sharepoint online before February release (online sp 2013) and it works on it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's because the ms-backgroundImage class overrides your declared style.  The trick is to make your style more specific than the default.

I learned this [here](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-css-classes-that-suck-and-save-the-day/)

Comment: This does not apply to most div:s, just one if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found that using this CSS selector combination allowed me to overwrite the OOB styling with my own:

```
body.ms-backgroundImage {
  background: url("/style%20library/img/bg-blue.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```